# How to get value of data-flag

Tags: javascript, php

Community, I have a select drop down which is trying to pass two variables to javascript.  The first variable is (source_id) and the second is (source_flag).

My select looks like the following...

```
<select id="ticket_source" name="ticket_source" onchange="showEmail(this)">
<option value="">Select Source</option>
```

I use query to populate remaining options.

```
$get_sources = mysql_query("select source_id, source_name, source_flag from ticket_source order by source_name ASC");
while(($source_list = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_sources)))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$source_list['source_id'].'" data-flag="'.$source_list['source_flag'].'">'.$source_list['source_name'].'</option>
}

<option value="0">Other</option>
</select>';
```

My javascript will make a hidden div appear.  I'm trying to obtain the value stored in the data-flag attribute, and I'm not quite sure if there is a certain route to do that.

```
function showEmail(element)
{
    var id = element.value;
    var divTwo = document.getElementById("ticket_source");
    var flag = divTwo.getAttribute('data-flag');
    alert(flag);
    // Do something with flag...
    var div = document.getElementById("received");
    if(id == 2 || id == 3 || id == 5)
    {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
   {
       div.style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this in pure javascript

```
var flag =document.getElementById('ticket_source').options[select.selectedIndex].data-flag;
```

or

```
var flag =element.options[element.selectedIndex].data-flag;
var flag =element.options[element.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-flag');
```

[**See Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/cpNPm/)

Comment: This won't work, HTML5 data attributes have to be accessed via the dataset property and non-HTML5 compliant browsers wouldn't recognize that either, you'd need to use the getAttribute method.

Comment: @dianuj I tried both of your methods.  Neither one was successful. I tried to alert the variable, flag, afterwards and it wouldn't pop up.

Comment: @callmehiphop that's why i have provided the example using `getAttribute` also thanks for pointing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var flag = document.querySelector('#ticket_source').dataset.flag; // using javascript
var flag = $('#ticket_source').data('flag'); // using jquery
```

JSBIN Link: http://jsbin.com/ujiday/228/

Comment: OP has not added jquery tag

Comment: I tried this, and the alert is coming up, but it keeps saying undefined.  I double checked my query and my database and both are fine.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you could do this

```
document.getElementById('myThing').dataset.flag
```

However, that won't work in non-HTML5 compliant browsers, so you'd want to use getAttribute like you've done in your code above.

Alternatively if you're using jQuery, Mohit Pandey's answer would be good.

Edit: Looking at your code, it also looks like you're trying to pull the data value from the select box, while in your PHP you're adding it to the options, which would explain why it was returning null/undefined.

Made a fiddle (using jQuery)
http://jsfiddle.net/QAsgN/